# How can I make an SSL-enabled HTTP request in Julia?

Tags: http, ssl, julia

I need to make a request to an internal web service, and need to provide a custom SSL certificate chain.

In python + requests, I would set the `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` environment variable to the path of the bundle, `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`. What is the equivalent with Julia's HTTP.jl? It doesn't seem to be picking up the bundle automatically.

Comment: IIRC the only way to do this currently is to add your root cert to `MbedTLS/deps/cacert.pem` (make sure you get the right MbedTLS version!) and rebuild MbedTLS afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP.jl uses MbedTLS to process certificates, so I wonder if your Julia install somehow is missing that library.  You might try installing MbedTLS directly for you platform and see where it looks for certificates by default.

Comment: HTTP.jl installed MbedTLS when it is installed. AFAIK there is no way to make it use a system install.

Comment: Perhaps reinstalling and rebuilding MbedTLS.jl would work, then?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://juliaweb.github.io/HTTP.jl/v0.6/) you can pass an `sslconfig` object to the call. You can supply the certificate to this object:

*Untested*

```
using HTTP, MbedTLS

conf = MbedTLS.SSLConfig(cert_file, key_file)
resp = HTTP.get("https://httpbin.org/ip", sslconfig=conf)

println(resp)
```